# Unable to access variable from included file

Tags: php, oop

As the title says there is a problem accessing variable (associative array) inside class from included file. Here is the source code both class and include file:

```
require("applications/cw_database.php");
require("config/dbConfig.php");
require("config/appConfig.php");

class APP_ASSESMENTS
{
    private $dbObj;
    private $DisplayOutput  = "";

    public function __construct($PageParams)
    {
        try
        {
            $dbObj = new CW_DB($dbConfig['hostname'],$dbConfig['username'],$dbConfig['password'],$dbConfig['name'],$dbConfig['port']);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new ErrorException($e);
        }
    }
...
```

The other part has nothing to do with $dbConfig.
Also this is the included file (config/dbConfig.php):

```
    /*
    Testing configuration for MySQL database
*/
$dbConfig['username']   = "phpcoursework";  // changed on demand
$dbConfig['password']   = "phpcoursework";  // changed on demand
$dbConfig['hostname']   = "localhost";      // changed on demand
$dbConfig['name']       = "students";       // changed on demand
$dbConfig['port']       = 3306;             // default for MySQL
```

Comment: If you don't pass `$dbConfig` to your class in some way, how do you expect that your class knows what it is? Answers are suggesting to use `global` keyword, which is an awful practice because it pollutes the variable space and you can easily create a mistake. If you need that variable, simply pass it to your constructor.

Comment: Including the file inside class and defining variable as global works.

Comment: If that looks like a good design to you, then have at it.

Comment: I would highly recommend against `global`, as @N.B. has. Considering you've already decided to take advantage of OOP, introducing global state in a class method is really walking backwards.

Comment: @N.B. it doesn't matter if this works good for me, but if this is the properly method how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `$dbObj` will not automatically assume class member scope, it will create a local copy of `CW_DB` and discard it when `__construct` returns. You need to explicitly reference the property;

```
$this->dbObj = ...
```

Anyway, global state using `global` as suggested by others will "*work*", but if you're using OOP practices you're best not to do that. You can actually return from an `include()`, so an option would be to do the following:

```
// your config file dbConfig.php
return array(
    'username' => "phpcoursework",
    'password' => "phpcoursework",
    'hostname' => "localhost",
    'name' => "students",
    'port' => 3306,
);
```

And inject it into the object, via constructor or method (*here's constructor*)

```
class APP_ASSESMENTS
{

    private $dbObj;

    public function __construct($dbConfig, $PageParams)
    {
        $dbObj = new CW_DB($dbConfig['hostname'], $dbConfig['username'],
            $dbConfig['password'], $dbConfig['name'], $dbConfig['port']);
        // ...
    }

}

// include() here, will actually return the array from the config file
$appAssesments = new \APP_ASSESMENTS(include('dbConfig.php'), $PageParams);
```

It would be recommended that you go another level up: instead, inject the database object itself, taking the dependency out of your `APP_ASSESSMENTS` class.

(*Also, PascalCase is the typical convention of class naming, such as `AppAssessments` and `CwDb`*)

---

```
$dbObj = new CwDb(include('dbConfig.php'));
$appAssessments = new AppAssessments($dbObj, $etc, $etc);
```

This simple change allows you to remove the dependency from `AppAssessments` on `CwDb`. That way, if you extend `CwDb` for some reason, you can just pass in an instance of the extended class without having to change any code in `AppAssessments`

You can change the `AppAssessments` constructor like so:

```
public function __construct(CwDb $db, $etc, $etc){
    $this->db = $db;
    // ...
}
```

This takes advantage of PHPs (*limited, albeit still useful*) type-hinting, ensuring the first argument is always of the correct type.

This plays into part of the open/closed principle: classes should be open to extension but closed for modification.

Comment: What do you mean by injecting object itself? Also thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @MaDDoC No problem :) By injecting the object itself, I mean create the instance of the database object *outside* of the `AppAssessments` object (*possibly right before*) and then pass the database object in, instead of the configuration. I'll edit to show.

Comment: Well i get it, but here is what is going on: I'm trying to use the MVC architecture to create web application, and I used to use index.php that is creating new instance of page controller that is going to be displayed. The controller itself also creates instance of page model which also create instance but this of database . I'm a bit confused is that right method for using this architecture...

Comment: @MaDDoC Is this a "*roll-your-own*" MVC framework, or are you working this into an existing one? I don't know how much you know about framework development, MVC pattern, etc., however I would suggest that if you haven't yet, you grab a copy of a popular MVC framework, and see how it approaches/solves problems using various patterns. I'm working on a framework myself (*it seems like nearly every PHP dev is*) and it is certainly no easy task.

Comment: I see a curious -1. I *invite* criticism :), but its helpful if an explanation follows.

Comment: I guess it will be better choice, as I don't know much about "writing own php framework". In fact my goal isn't writing own that FW that will be used in other applications, but so far I guess that is what is going on. Well maybe some "simple-to-use" (if may say so) such as CodeIgniter will get the job done. :) Anyway I'm still interested in learning how to build own framework, but I don't have much time right now to make a such. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8920/discussion-between-maddoc-and-bracketworks)

Comment: @MaDDoC Unfortunately, I have to be off; however PHP chat has some great individuals who are equally (*likely more*) well-versed on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

Includes are used in the scope of access. So, to access the variables you need to include the files within your class. As earlier mentioned global will let you access variables from another scope too. But global should be used with caution! See the documentation.

[See the manual for more information.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Edit: I need to make it clear that globals are never a good alternative for handling these kind of critical variables..

Answer (score -1):

```
public function __construct($PageParams){
    global $dbConfig;
    try{
        $dbObj = new CW_DB($dbConfig['hostname'],$dbConfig['username'],$dbConfig['password'],$dbConfig['name'],$dbC    onfig['port']);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new ErrorException($e);
    }
}
```

or you could use `$GLOBALS['dbConfig']`.